# UITextField has black insets when width constraint animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

So I'm changing a `UITextField`'s width constraint by calling `[self viewLayoutIfNeeded]` in `[UIView animateWithDuration:]`. The text field width constraint's starting width is 20, then I reset it to 250, and call `viewLayoutIfNeeded`. When that happens, it resizes appropriately, but with strange black insets on the sides. I'm not working with shadows or anything. Has anyone dealt with this or have a solution?

The views are set in my storyboard, and I dragged an `NSLayoutConstraint` for the width constraint, which is the only property being mutated.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textFieldWidthConst;
@end 

@implementation ViewController
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    _textFieldWidthConst.constant = 275;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion: nil 
    }];
}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the text field's content mode to “Redraw”:

[image: View content mode in Interface Builder]

If you want to do it in code, set the text field's `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.